# ssh X11Forwarding Gtk-WARNING **: 22:56:39.694: cannot open display: 10.255.255.202:0

Tags: ssh, x11, remote

I have an Ubuntu server on the local net I can ssh to an run say gedit. It works just fine.

And a remote Red Hat 7 through a VPN connection which fails.
I connect with the command:

```
ssh -X -o ForwardX11=yes -o ForwardX11Trusted=yes rhsrv
```

and then I get the fail:

```
$ gedit 
(gedit:3085): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:13:00.902: cannot open display: 10.255.255.202:0
```

To verify I run a few commands:

```
# is DISPLAY set?
$ echo $DISPLAY 
10.255.255.202:0

# Exists the .Xauthority ?
$ strings ~/.Xauthority
MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1

$ xauth list
rhsrv:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  43f5b66044bf4645cde63c22213a0c28

$ xauth info
Authority file:       /home/joe/.Xauthority
File new:             no
File locked:          no
Number of entries:    1
Changes honored:      yes
Changes made:         no
Current input:        (argv):1

# Is route back to client pc open? yes:
$ ssh 10.255.255.202 22
joe@10.255.255.202's password:

# IPv6 problems? no:
$ sudo egrep "^(X|Ad)" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
AddressFamily inet
X11Forwarding yes
X11UseLocalhost no

$ rpm -qa | grep x11
xorg-x11-apps-7.7-7.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-font-utils-7.5-21.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-fonts-Type1-7.5-9.el7.noarch
xorg-x11-xauth-1.0.9-1.el7.x86_64
```

I have tried to `rm ~/.Xauthority` to get a fresh file with no luck.

I have tried `ssh -Y` without luck.

After changing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I have run:

```
# systemctl reload sshd
# systemctl restart sshd
# cat /var/run/sshd.pid | xargs kill -1
```

On the client pc I ran a verbose task `ssh -vv` and looked in the output `rhsrv` file for clues but it looks jolly good:

```
$ egrep "(Req|[Xx]11)" rhsrv
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug2: x11_get_proto: /usr/bin/xauth  list :0 2>/dev/null
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug2: channel 0: request x11-req confirm 1
debug1: Requesting authentication agent forwarding.
debug2: X11 forwarding request accepted on channel 0
```

Another user on this internal network and server reports no problem while running Emacs in GUI. His routing to the server is a bit different as he connect to the network interface `ens192` (172.23.x.x) where I connect to the alias `ens193` (10.x.x.x). His `$DISPLAY` variable says:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
pd9993b1.example.org:0
```

So he has a valid reverse DNS lookup while I don't. It was expected that the `$DISPLAY` should read something like `localhost:10.0` but despite of that he runs GUI fine.

The routing is like this (but should not be relevant):

```
$ /sbin/routel 
     target         gateway source    proto  scope    dev tbl
    default     172.23.10.1          static        ens192 
10.255.0.0/ 16  10.255.20.1          static        ens193
```

Is there any logfile or something I have missed to look for?

Comment: Display zero is nearly **always** the local display.  ssh X11 forwarding spoofs the display... usually the default display number of `:10` or something like that... which seems to actually match your xauth cookie... so, something seems confused about the information in the question...

Comment: `10.255.255.202:0` is wrong.  Are you setting this in `.profile` or `.bash_profile` or similar?  It _should_ read something like `localhost:10.0` to point to your tunnel.

Comment: Yes that $DISPLAY looked a bit odd to me but I have not done anything to change it. I am cooperating this server with other people so I might ask around if anybody knows about it. I have tried `export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0` but did not change anything. A `grep DISPLAY -Is /etc/*` did not show anything either. Or in the homedir `grep DISPLAY ~/.* -Is` .